# How to delay sequence based on previous callback return

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

I'm not sure if this i possible through sequence:

```
cc.sequence(
        cc.callFunc(this.func, this), // returns 5 for next delay
        cc.delayTime(5_seconds_delay_from_previous_function),
        cc.callFunc(this.func_2, this), // returns n for next delay
        cc.delayTime(n_seconds_delay_from_previous_function),
        cc.callFunc(this.func_3, this),
        ....
    );
```

Is there any optimal way to this? as much as possible the cocos way.

Comment: If it returns 5, then store it in a variable and pass it into the next function?

Comment: @Kobe i think that's that's the whole point of the question, how tho?

Comment: `delay = cc.callFunc(this.func, this)`, `cc.delayTime(delay)`?

Comment: @Kobe i tried it, it doesn't work. it doesn't store any value to the variable inside sequence

Comment: Okay, so what returns 5? Do you have to use sequence here? Can't you just async await?

Comment: @Kobe the function returns 5 but I think sequence is already setting all function thus there's no way to adjust the cc.delayTime dynamically once it's running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195848/discussion-between-kobe-and-acd).